# HC-08 Bluetooth module not showing up on iPad

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I have an HC-08 Bluetooth module Bluetooth module hooked up to an Arduino Uno but for some reason, it doesn’t show up in the Bluetooth menu in my iPad settings. Can you help?

Comment: Can you check, if you show up on other devices? Maybe you have access to an android device? That can show you, if the problem is with the iPad side or with the HC-08 side

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Comment: Just tried that and it worked. Weird.

Comment: [This article](https://www.aeq-web.com/arduino-hc08-bluetooth-module-ios-serial-controller/?lang=en) describes, that the HC-08 should work with iPhones. I think iPads are similar. Maybe on your iPad try to turn off and on bluetooth, restart the iPad or try to update it. Difficult to say, what the problem is here. And we are experts in Arduino, not in iPads.